# How to get and use custom values in the Prestashop shopping cart

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am new to Prestashop and not quite familiar with the structure of it, but i did manage to setup a custom product field called `quantity_step` using a tutorial, which is going to be used by the quantity input to determine the step size.

In the product page template `product-add-to-cart.tpl` there is absolutely no problem getting the value of my custom field `{$product.quantity_step}`

```html
<input
  type="text"
  name="qty"
  id="quantity_wanted"
  value="{$product.quantity_wanted}"
  class="input-group"
  step="{$product.quantity_step}" 
  min="{$product.minimal_quantity}"
  aria-label="{l s='Quantity' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}"
/>
```

On the other hand, i can't seem to get it to work in the cart template `cart-detailed-product-line.tpl`:

```html
<input
  class="js-cart-line-product-quantity"
  data-down-url="{$product.down_quantity_url}"
  data-up-url="{$product.up_quantity_url}"
  data-update-url="{$product.update_quantity_url}"
  data-product-id="{$product.id_product}"
  type="text"
  value="{$product.quantity}"
  name="product-quantity-spin"
  step="{$product.quantity_step}"
  min="{$product.minimal_quantity}"
/>
```

My custom field returns `null`, while the built in field `{$product.minimal_quantity}` is working of course.

I have a strong feeling i need to change some file somewhere to add my custom value to the `{$product}`-object, i just can't find that file, as i don't know what to look for :(

If it helps, i am using the `classic` theme.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to save the value in the DB when the product is added to the Cart and that will be done in the CartController.php class file in postProcess() function.

**My Recommendation:** You should create a separate DB table for saving the value of your custom field and leave the default Cart and Product object(s) alone, else you will face some serious issues with the core functionalities of PrestaShop.

Comment: I'm using a module which extends the product control panel and lets you add custom fields, so i haven't really modified any source code. The value is stored in the same table tho, and i think the product page grabs the whole thing, while the cart doesn't.

Comment: Do you know how i could get a value from the database to be displayed/used the cart?

Comment: I think you are looking for a module... Suggestion: https://www.knowband.com/prestashop-advance-product-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Look up in the src/Adapter/Cart/CartPresenter.php method presentProduct I think it is that what are you need. Just add new parameter to $rawProduct['quantity_step'] = 'value'

Comment: Hmm.. this looks like a set value to me. The value differs from product to product, so it has to come from the database somehow.